# Read csv to a list of objects and send row by row via mqtt publisher with an interval of 30 seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, mqtt

I need to read a csv file has a list of objects to then do a json.dump and send row by row in a 30 seconds interval. I've got this but it is not working well, it sends a row but it is not the first and after 30 seconds stops for some reason.

```
data = []
c = ('id', 'room_id', 'noted_date', 'temp', 'out_in')
with open('online.data.csv', 'r') as file:
    leitor = csv.DictReader(file, fieldnames=c, delimiter=',')
    next(leitor)
    for each in leitor:
        d = {}
        #print (each)
        for field in c:
            d[field] = each[field]
            #print(field)
    data.append(d)
    #print(data)

def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    print ('You pressed Ctrl+C.\nProgram closed.')
    sys.exit(0)

def main(argv):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

    num_msgs_send = len(data)
    mqttc = mqtt.Client('Publisher')
    mqttc.connect(broker, port)
    msgs_sent = 0
    mqttc.loop_start()
    for i in range(num_msgs_send):
        try:
            payload = json.dumps(data[i])
            print (payload)
            print ('Sending msg: ' + payload)
            mqttc.publish(topic, payload)
            msgs_sent += 1
            time.sleep(30)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.exit()
    mqttc.loop_stop()
    print ('Messages sent: ' + str(msgs_sent))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you might want to hide the IP address/port of your broker in this code sample to prevent request flooding.

Comment: thanks, i've edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong, you are only adding the last record to `data` because `data.append(d)` is outside the first for-loop

```
with open('online.data.csv', 'r') as file:
    leitor = csv.DictReader(file, fieldnames=c, delimiter=',')
    next(leitor)
    for each in leitor:
        d = {}
        #print (each)
        for field in c:
            d[field] = each[field]
            #print(field)
        data.append(d)
    #print(data)
```